# How to remove \n character from a sentence using strip()

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline, strip

I am trying to remove `\n` character from a sentence using `strip()` command, But it doesn't seem to work.

```
str1 = "Hello World \n, I\n am \nhere"
print(str1.strip())
```

Output

```
Hello World 
, I
 am 
here
```

Comment: Strip removes characters **from the start and end** only. Your newlines are not at the start or end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strip()` only removes whitespace characters (newline, tab, space) from start and the end. To remove in between `\n` use `replace()`

```
>>> str1 = "Hello World \n, I\n am \nhere"
>>> print(str1.replace('\n', ''))
Hello World , I am here
>>>
```

Comment: A better thing to do is to find the duplicate and vote to close this question as a duplicate. You can then post such a solution on the duplicate, where it will be seen by more people and likely get more up-votes.

Comment: `strip()` removes all _blank_ characters, not only newlines, but tabs, spaces, carriage returns, vertical tabulations...